# Author parsing with JSOUP

Tags: java, html, parsing, html-parsing

There is my html input:

```
  <!-- left panel --> 
  <div class="left-panel"> 
    <p class="article-published"> 1. júl 2015 o 17:35 &nbsp;&nbsp; Marek Hudec, Dávid Tvrdoň </p>
  </div>
```

and the code:

```
if(doc.select("p[class=article-published]").isEmpty() == FALSE){
    Elements description = doc.select("p[class=article-published]");
    for (Element link : description) {
        author4 = link.text();
    }
    System.out.println("AUTHORS :" + author4);
 }
```

I would like to get the output, like: Marek Hudec, Dávid Tvrdoň. So only the name of those guys. But yet I can not got it. Someone help me please. Thank you

Comment: JSoup can only get you the contents between the tag, which you've already done. Figuring out what is a name and what is a date isn't a problem for JSoup. If the format you presented is consistent, then you could skip over the initial date and time (you know what a date and time will look like, so you find it and print the stuff after it).

Comment: I should verify though, are you getting the right contents in the first place (the date, time, plus authors) or something else entirely?

Comment: The problem is that, I dont get nothing... only empty output with the code above.

Comment: Ahh, but it still compiles? `FALSE` should be `false`, unless you are defining some constant `FALSE` above.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is to parse the Text you get from Jsoup  and chop the data you want from it, in below code i modified your code to get the data from specific index.

```
 import java.util.Arrays;
 import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
 import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
 import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
 import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

 public class KolosParsor {   
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String author4 = null;
            Document doc = Jsoup.parse("<div class=\"left-panel\">"+ 
             "<p class=\"article-published\"> 1. júl 2015 o 17:35 &nbsp;&nbsp; Marek Hudec,Dávid Tvrdoň </p>");
            if(!doc.select("p[class=article-published]").isEmpty()){
                Elements description = doc.select("p[class=article-published]");
                for (Element link : description) {
                     author4 = link.text();
                 }
                 System.out.println("DATA :" + Arrays.asList(author4.split(" ")));
                 System.out.println("AUTHORS :" + Arrays.asList(author4.split(" ")).get(7));
             }          
        }
    }
```

Comment: But I need, to parse not only this example, but there are lot... this is only one of them. So I need one universal code for doing this step.

Comment: this is just an example for one kinda parsing, webpages / html is so diffrent in universe you cant write universal code for it, though i would recommend to look at   `apache nutch`+`apache tika` for your requirement.

Comment: The structure of the other html`s are like this one... only difference is date and the autors name. But div class and p class are equal to this one.

Comment: thats where this code will help you ... just put it in a loop, think little bit how you can how you can do same process again n again in loop